# Create Impala Table from HDFS Directory with subdirectories

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, impala

I have a directory, such as `/user/name/folder`.

Inside this directory, I have more sub-directories named `dt=2020-06-01`, `dt=2020-06-02`, `dt=2020-06-03`, etc.

These directories contain parquet files. They all have the same schema.

Is it possible to create an Impala table using `/user/name/folder`?

Each time I do, I get a Table with 0 records. Is there a way to tell Impala to pull the parquet files from all of the sub-directories?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do that is loading data with static partitioning in which you manually define the different partitions. With static partitioning, you create a partition manually, using an ALTER TABLE … ADD PARTITION statement, 
and then load the data into the partition.

```sql
CREATE TABLE customers_by_date 
        (cust_id STRING, name STRING) 
PARTITIONED BY (dt STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET;

ALTER TABLE customers_by_country 
ADD PARTITION (dt='2020-06-01') 
SET LOCATION '/user/name/folder/dt=2020-06-01';
```

If the location is not specified then the location is created

```sql
ALTER TABLE customers_by_date
ADD PARTITION (dt='2020-06-01');
```

and you could load data with HDFS commands too

```
$ hdfs dfs -cp /user/name/folder/dt=2020-06-01 /user/directory_impala/table/partition
```

You could follow these links to the Cloudera documentation for further details:

[Partitioning for Impala Tables](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_partitioning.html)

[Impala Create table statement](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_create_table.html#create_table)

[Impala Alter table statement](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-9-x/topics/impala_alter_table.html#alter_table)